# wso2 dss how to implement IP filter

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am running wso2dss-3.2.1 on windows server 2012, and expose my database data as service. Now I want to limit only some IP is allowed to access my data services. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can throttle out ips from accessing you WSO2 DSS Data service. 
After you create the data service,

- Click on the service you created
- Click on "Access Throttling" under the section "Quality of Service Configuration"
- Enable throttling by selecting from drop down
- Add any IPs and Domains that you want to allow and select "Allow" at access column
- Add another entry and keep "other" as 'Range' and select "Deny" at access column
- Click on "Finish"

Refer following for more details, https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS321/Access+Throttling

Thanks.